# Filter Model Prediction DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
lang_df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Content ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                                'User ID': [10, 11, 10, 11, 10, 11],
                                'Language': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']})

pred_df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Content ID': [4, 7, 14, 6, 6, 6],
                                'User ID': [10, 11, 10, 11, 10, 11],
                                'Language': ['A', 'D', 'Z', 'B', 'B', 'A']})
```

I want to filter out the rows in the second dataframe so that users only get content IDs in languages they have previously watched. Result for this example would look like:

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Content ID':  [4, 6, 6, 6],
                                    'User ID':  [10, 11, 10, 11],
                                    'Language': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A']})
```

I know how to do it using a for loop, but this seems highly inefficient. Not sure how to make the DFs appear in the question for better clarity.

Comment: This: `pred_df[pred_df['Language'].isin(lang_df['Language'])]`? In that case a dupe of something.

Comment: From where does `result_df` have `Content ID` 8?

Comment: @AntonvBR No, because each user can watch content in any language, I want each user to get back content in languages they have watched, not just all the language in first DF.

Comment: @HarvIpan fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a inner join on the columns `User ID` and `Language` from `lang_df` with `pred_df`.

```
lang_df[['User ID', 'Language']].merge(pred_df, on=['User ID', 'Language'])
```

Output:

```
     User ID Language  Content ID
0       10        A           4
1       11        A           6
2       10        B           6
3       11        B           6
```

Comment: I like your aswer too!

Comment: selected as answer for simplicity when I read it/based on my current understanding of merge. thanks for your help @HarvIpan

Answer (score 3):

You can use inner join with `merge` to accomplish this, then use column filtering to on return columns from the pred_df dataframe:

```
pred_df.merge(lang_df, on=['User ID','Language'], suffixes=('','_2'))[pred_df.columns]
```

Output:

```
   Content ID  User ID Language
0           4       10        A
1           6       11        B
2           6       10        B
3           6       11        A
```